# Dropdown list returning and saving data

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I am trying to return a dropdown list with data already stored in the database, I want to be able to show the value set in the database and then allow user to change it.

The following code sort of works, but it doesn't show the country stored in the database but displays all other countries in the dropdown list.

I am a novice PHP programmer and often get myself into trouble with the coding:(

```
<select id='rcorners' name='psychic_addr_group[country]'>";
    $data .= "<option".(($country == 'AUD') ? 'selected' : '')." value='AUD'>Australia</option>";
    $data .= "<option".(($country == 'CAD') ? 'selected' : '')." value='CAD'>Canada</option>";
    $data .= "<option".(($country == 'GBP') ? 'selected' : '')." value='GBP'>United Kingdom</option>";
    $data .= "<option".(($country == 'EUR') ? 'selected' : '')." value='EUR'>Italy</option>";
    $data .= "<option".(($country == 'USD') ? 'selected' : '')." value='USD'>United States</option>";
    $data .= "</select>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give a space after: <option